Is it possible to use boldface for part of a fancyvrb element?
I would like to highlight the word main in the following:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\&\[\]]
    #include <stdio.h>

    int &textbf[main]() {
      printf("Hello World!");
      return 0;
    }
\end{Verbatim}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

I'm fairly certain that I've got the syntax correct, since the compiler doesn't complain, and &textbf doesn't appear in the result, but the output that I get does not show any boldface:


The main reason for this is because the default (Computer Modern) fonts don't have a bold monospaced font. It just sets it as medium. Adding \usepackage{lmodern} (or something similar) to your preamble would extend it to include a bold monospaced font.

See How do I get \texttt with bold face in LaTeX?
